# how to upload functions to AWS Lambda using lambda-maven-plugin?

Tags: aws-lambda

How can i upload my Lambda function written in Java using Lambda_Maven_Plugin?
I want to define all the parameters like function name, memory, time out parameters using maven and deploy the function to Lambda using maven command.
Can someone share the details on this please?
I have tried the code mentioned as per this blog.

https://dzone.com/articles/building-serverless-on-aws-lambda

running maven command on the Lambda function throws error.
[ERROR] Could not find goal 'deploy-lambda' in plugin br.com.ingenieux:lambda-maven-plugin:1.5.2 among available goals deploy-functions, help, list-aliases -> [Help 1]